# Jsf 2 - ajax event update

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I am trying to update a dropdown on change of value in a previous dropdown(in another form,another xhtml file). This is the code that am using as of now :

...

```
    <f:selectItems value="#{createbill.episodeSetting}"/>
<p:ajax event="change" update=":chargesForm:tab2:serviceSetting"></p:ajax>
```

...

when this value is changed, i require the same value to show up in the other dropdown,which is in a different form(chargesForm) which is in a different file. The important thing to note is that both the dropdowns have the same values.

This code is not functioning as i per the requirement I mentioned above.
Please suggest...

Comment: Ajax between two defferent pages?! How? Are you pages open in defferent tabs? That's simply not possible. This is not the way web pages work.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn Being in different files doesn't mean they can't be in same DOM tree when rendered. Just check it.

Comment: Oh yes! Sorry, I'm not a web expert! Thanks for the info.

Comment: the pages open in different tabs, in the above code i refer it through the form names